# Bash script and xml/rss parsing

Tags: xml, bash, parsing, xml-parsing, xmllint

i'm writing a small script that parse an rss using xmllint.

Now i fetch the titles list with the following command:

```
ITEMS=`echo "cat //title" | xmllint --shell rss.xml `
echo $ITEMS > tmpfile
```

But it returns:

```
<title>xxx</title> ------- <title>yyy :)</title> ------- <title>zzzzzz</title>
```

without newlines, or space. 
Now i'm interested only in the text content of title tags, and if possible i want to navigate through the titles using a for/while loop, something like:

```
for  val in $ITEMS 
do
       echo $val
done
```

How it can be done? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't be a masochist, use a script language like python, ruby, any other language in the world, perl (in that order of preference :P)

Comment: @KurzedMetal You can do plenty of parsing and splitting and iterating in bash.

Comment: You will find that quoting your variables will help a lot: `for  val in "$ITEMS"; do echo "$val"; done`

Comment: Thanks, it could help, but if i try that for, "$val" contains the whole string and the cycle run only one time, but it print $val with correct newlines. I need to read $ITEMS line by line, how i can do it?

Comment: Is something wrong with `xmllint --xpath '//title/text()' rss.xml`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same type of requirement at some point to parse xml in bash. I ended up using xmlstarlet http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/ which you might be able to install.

If not, something like that will remove the surounding tags:

```
echo "cat  //title/text()" | xmllint --shell  rss.xml
```

Then you will need to cleanup the output after piping it, a basic solution would be:

```
echo "cat  //title/text()" | xmllint --shell  rss.xml  | egrep '^\w'
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question, The unquoted use of `$ITEMS` with `echo` is eliminating your new-line chars. Try

```
ITEMS=`echo "cat //title" | xmllint --shell rss.xml `
echo "$ITEMS" > tmpfile
#----^------^--- dbl-quotes only
```

In general, using `for` loops is best left to items that won't generate unexpected spaces or other non-printable characters. (non-alphanumerics), like `for i in {1..10} ; do echo $i; done`

AND you don't really need the variables, or the tempfile, try

```
  echo "cat //title" | xmllint --shell rss.xml |
  while read line ; do
      echo "$line"
  done
```

Depending on what is in your rrs feed, you may also benefit from changing the default IFS (Internal Field Separator) that is used by the read cmd, try

```
while IFS= read line ....
# or 
while IFS="\n" read line
# or
while IFS="\r\n" read line
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with `echo "cat //title" |` going into xmllint, so I'm leaving it as is. Is that an instruction to xmllint? or is it passed thru to create a header to the document? (Don't have xmllint to expermient with right now).

Also, you might want to look at [reading rss feeds with awk](http://awk.info/?doc/tools/myrss.html), but it is rather low level.

I hope this helps.

Comment: yes is  an instruction to xmllint, please check that i updated the question, because i noticed some charcater missing in the example  that i provided. Thanks :D

Comment: I don't see anything different between your new posting and what I hav e used as your main command. Was the change in the cmd or in your sample current output? **also I am adding an edit to my answer, check back in a minute.** Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Philippe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10553095/4375327), if you want to get the xml output **directly** from a **command** like **`cURL`**, you can use [another file descriptor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18899/138686) to pipe it.

Indeed, STDIN is already taken by `xmllintt` shell inputs. Below a working example (just remember to replace the URL argument with yours).

```
# Create a temporary file and use it as third fd
exec 3<> $(tempfile) &&
# cURL the RSS URL and redirect STDOUT to the 3rd fd
curl https://your-url/to/some/rss.xml >&3 &&
# Then read  fd 3 with xmllint
xmllint --format --shell /dev/fd/3 <<< 'cat //title/text()' | egrep '^\w' &&
# Close the temporary file (remember global warming issues)
exec 3>&-
```